# Link creation from LIST extracting text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem creating a new  links using the "master link value" + values inside slug=" " automatically or by clicking a "button"

master link value = http://google.com

```
 <ul class="linktree">
 <li class="jstree" slug="link-1.html" src="1"><a href="#">Link Text 1</a></li>
 <li class="jstree" slug="link-2.html" src="1"><a href="#">Link Text 2</a></li>
 <li class="jstree" slug="link-3.html" src="1"><a href="#">Link Text 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

it should look like this:

```
 <ul class="linktree">
 <li class="jstree"><a href="http://google.com/link-1.html">Link Text 1</a></li>
 <li class="jstree"><a href="http://google.com/link-1.html">Link Text 2</a></li>
 <li class="jstree"><a href="http://google.com/link-1.html">Link Text 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop using forEach

```js
const masterLinkValue = 'https://google.com';
document.querySelectorAll('.linktree li.jstree').forEach(li => {
  const slug = li.getAttribute('slug');
  li.removeAttribute('slug');
  li.removeAttribute('src');
  //const url = new URL(`${masterLinkValue}/${slug}`); // needs url.toString()
  li.querySelector('a').href = `${masterLinkValue}/${slug}`; // simpler but no error handling
})
```

```html
<ul class="linktree">
  <li class="jstree" slug="link-1.html#div3" src="1"><a href="#">Link Text 1</a></li>
  <li class="jstree" slug="link-2.html" src="1"><a href="#">Link Text 2</a></li>
  <li class="jstree" slug="link-3.html" src="1"><a href="#">Link Text 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,  I ran into some URLs that have "#" in it, the script is skipping the #, and I cant figure it out, even try to encode %23. thank you in advance.

Comment: See update. I wanted to create the URL outside the function, but now I create it from the masterLinkValue plus the slug